# Execute Thread in every Viewpager item

Tags: android, multithreading, android-layout, android-viewpager

- I have two images, in single viewpager item. When i am clicking on any image it display a line, simple line.
- I am growing this line using thread, line is percentage of vote that are given to particular image, based on percentage lines are drawn on both image after click
- But problem is that if i click on one image single line is drawn on that particular image, and every other viewpager items no line is drawn on click
- I want two lines after click on any image, so what to do

```java
ivImageOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {

        id = arraylist.get(position).get("user_id1");

        feed_id = arraylist.get(position).get("feed_id");
        Log.e("feeeeeee", feed_id);

        View tempView = (View) v.getTag(R.integer.btnminusview);
        Integer pos = (Integer) v.getTag(R.integer.btnminuspos);
        ivRightTick = (ImageView) tempView.findViewById(R.id.ivRightTick);

        ivLeftTick = (ImageView) tempView.findViewById(R.id.ivLeftTick);

        ivLeftTick.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ivRightTick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        vOne = (View) tempView.findViewById(R.id.vOne);
        vTwo = (View) tempView.findViewById(R.id.vTwo);

        mThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                while (pStatus < pcount1) {
                    pStatus += 10;

                    handler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = vOne.getLayoutParams();
                            params.height = pStatus;
                            params.width = 10;
                            Log.d("pppppppppppppp", params.height + "");
                            vOne.setLayoutParams(params);

                            // vOne.setLayoutParams(new WindowManager.LayoutParams(1,pStatus));
                            if (pStatus == pcount1) {
                                stopThread(mThread);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(19); //thread will take approx 2.5 seconds to finish
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        };


        mThread2 = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                while (pStatus2 > MIN_VALUE) {
                    pStatus2 += 10;

                    handler2.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = vTwo.getLayoutParams();
                            params.height = pStatus;
                            params.width = 10;
                            Log.d("pppppppppppppp", params.height + "");
                            vTwo.setLayoutParams(params);
                            // vOne.setLayoutParams(new WindowManager.LayoutParams(1,pStatus));
                            if (pStatus2 == pcount2) {
                                stopThread(mThread2);
                            }

                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(19); //thread will take approx 2.5 seconds to finish
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        };

        mThread.start();
        mThread2.start();
    }
});


ivFeedImageTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //  giveVote(2);

        id = arraylist.get(position).get("user_id2");
        feed_id = arraylist.get(position).get("feed_id");

        View tempView = (View) v.getTag(R.integer.btnminusview);
        Integer pos = (Integer) v.getTag(R.integer.btnminuspos);
        ivLeftTick = (ImageView) tempView.findViewById(R.id.ivLeftTick);
        ivRightTick = (ImageView) tempView.findViewById(R.id.ivRightTick);
        ivLeftTick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ivRightTick.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        vOne = (View) tempView.findViewById(R.id.vOne);
        vTwo = (View) tempView.findViewById(R.id.vTwo);

        mThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                while (pStatus < pcount2) {
                    pStatus += 10;

                    handler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = vTwo.getLayoutParams();
                            params.height = pStatus;
                            params.width = 10;
                            Log.d("pppppppppppppp", params.height + "");
                            vTwo.setLayoutParams(params);
                            // vOne.setLayoutParams(new WindowManager.LayoutParams(1,pStatus));
                            if (pStatus == pcount2) {
                                stopThread(mThread);
                            }

                        }
                    });
                    try {

                        Thread.sleep(19); //thread will take approx 2.5 seconds to finish
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }


            }
        };

        mThread2 = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                while (pStatus2 > MIN_VALUE) {
                    pStatus2 += 10;

                    handler2.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = vOne.getLayoutParams();
                            params.height = pStatus;
                            params.width = 10;
                            Log.d("pppppppppppppp", params.height + "");
                            vOne.setLayoutParams(params);
                            // vOne.setLayoutParams(new WindowManager.LayoutParams(1,pStatus));
                            if (pStatus2 == pcount1) {
                                stopThread(mThread2);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(19); //thread will take approx 2.5 seconds to finish
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        };

        mThread2.start();
        mThread.start();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you handle your immediate problem:

Code a method on your activity/fragment that starts the animation for the two lines.  Then set up two identical `OnClickListener`s, one on each image, that simply call the animation method.

What I'm more concerned about is your use of `Thread`s for the animation.  That is not the Android way.  You should use an animator to make the visual change to your view.  The code could be as simple as:

```
        float pct = ... // ratio of votes to total votes, from 0.0 to 1.0

        vOne.setScaleX(0F);
        vOne.animate().setDuration(150).scaleXBy(pct).start();
```

Please look at some of the animation tutorials on the Android Developers site and elsewhere on the web.